# cytoscape.js text-background-padding not working

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

text-background-padding not work

set `text-background-padding` to the node

```js
         style: [
           {
             selector: "node",
             css: {
               "label": "data(name)",
               "text-valign": "center",
               "text-halign": "center",
               "shape": "rectangle",
               "border-width": 1,
               "border-color": "white",
               "border-style": "dotted",
               "color": "skyblue",
               "width": "100%",
               // "width": 'label',
               "text-background-padding": 20, 
             },
           },
         ]
```

online result:

```css
#cy {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
 <div id="app">
    <div id="cy"></div>
 </div>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.9/cytoscape.min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello!'
    },
    mounted() {

      setTimeout(()=>{
      const cy = cytoscape({
         container: document.getElementById("cy"),
 
         boxSelectionEnabled: false,
         autounselectify: true,
         style: [
           {
             selector: "node",
             css: {
               "label": "data(name)",
               "text-valign": "center",
               "text-halign": "center",
               "shape": "rectangle",
               "border-width": 1,
               "border-color": "white",
               "border-style": "dotted",
               "color": "skyblue",
               "width": "100%",
               // "width": 'label',
               "text-background-padding": 50, 
             },
           },
         ],
         elements: {
           nodes: [
             {
               data: {
                 id: "a",
                 name: "hello,cytoscape",
               },
             },       
           ],
         },
       });
          
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
  

  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no CSS property *text-background-padding* that I'm aware of, it's neither documented in MDN nor caniuse.com

Comment: @PatrickHund I'm using cytoscape.js. not use pure css

Answer (score 2):

Actually it works, but since `text-background-opacity` is set to 0 as default, you cannot see it. In the below example, I set it to 1 and applied a blue `text-background-color` together with a `text-background-padding` of 20. You can see the padding around the label.

```css
#cy {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
 <div id="app">
    <div id="cy"></div>
 </div>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.9/cytoscape.min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   
   var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello!'
    },
    mounted() {

      setTimeout(()=>{
      const cy = cytoscape({
         container: document.getElementById("cy"),
 
         boxSelectionEnabled: false,
         autounselectify: true,
         style: [
           {
             selector: "node",
             css: {
               "label": "data(name)",
               "text-valign": "center",
               "text-halign": "center",
               "shape": "rectangle",
               "border-width": 1,
               "border-color": "white",
               "border-style": "dotted",
               "color": "skyblue",
               "width": 200,
               "height": 150,
               // "width": 'label',
               "text-background-color": "blue",
               "text-background-opacity": 1,
               "text-background-padding": 20, 
             },
           },
         ],
         elements: {
           nodes: [
             {
               data: {
                 id: "a",
                 name: "hello,cytoscape",
               },
             },       
           ],
         },
       });
          
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
  

  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```